# Spring batch: Set maximum index of the items to be read for MultiResourceItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am use `MultiResourceItemReader` to read *csv files from source with `FlatFileItemReader` delegate.

My purpose is to read all data as it posible and training model based on this all data. I can not limit chunk size and train model by patition. I can only limit the total number of read data.

How i can do this?
`FlatFileItemReader` has method `.setMaxItemCount(int count)`, that set maximum of the items to be read. But it applies to the current reading resource. And when multy raeder begin to read new resource, it close the old by causing `delegate.close();` from `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader`:

```
@Override
public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
    super.close();
    currentItemCount = 0;
    try {
        doClose();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ItemStreamException("Error while closing item reader", e);
    }
}
```

And zeroes `currentItemCount`. So it does not suit me.

Another idea is to set chunkSize. But how to stop reading when chunk size is approached?

Of course, i can extends `MultiResourceItemReader`, set `maximumItemCount` and override `read()` function with appropriate check.

But I can not believe that MultiResourceItemReader has no opportunity to limit items to be read.

Please, suggest me best way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of items to read is a property of the delegate (per resource) that's why you cannot set it on the `MultiResourceItemReader` itself. But I see your point, you are looking for a global counter on all resources.

In order to achieve this, I would also suggest to extend the `MultiResourceItemReader` with a global counter and then override the `read` method appropriately.